# TMUX -- How to percentage split?

Tags: shell, tmux

This use to work ---
Now, it seem like  "-p " sizing longer work.
Is there any workaround?

```
!/bin/sh
    
tmux new-session  -s "Local" -d
tmux send-keys "" C-m ;  
tmux split-window -h  
tmux send-keys "  " C-m
tmux split-window -v  
tmux send-keys " " C-m
 
tmux selectp -t 0  
tmux split-window -p 27  
tmux send-keys " "  
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on [su].